# Make an actor sleep

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, actor

I want to make an actor sleep for a while, specifically it should decide whether to sleep **itself** depending on a condition:

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  def receive {
    case "doWork" => doWork()
  }

  def doWork(): Unit = {
    // doing some work
    val condition = calculateCondition
    if (condition) {
      // sleep for 5 seconds
      // Thread.sleep(5000) 
    }
  }
}
```

I'm pretty much sure it's not a good thing to call `Thread.sleep(5000)`  inside an actor and there should be another way. Therefore, how do I make it sleep?

Comment: what would be the intention of the sleep? To do something after the sleep time or to prevent the actor for accepting messages in that period?  thread.sleep in an actor does not make sense, so the intention/requirement is important to find a solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would look to do this using changes of state/behaviour for the Actor. Akka gives you a couple of means of doing this: you can implement a full-on state machine, or make use of `context.become` (and mix in `akka.actor.Stash`), and have the actor pass (scheduled) messages to itself. The former feels like overkill for this case, so here is how I would look to code it up:

```
import akka.actor._    
import scala.concurrent.duration._

class MySleepyActor(duration: FiniteDuration = (5 seconds)) extends Actor with Stash {

  import context._

  override def preStart() { become(running) }

  def receive = PartialFunction.empty

  def running: Actor.Receive = {
    case "doWork" =>       
      if (doWork()) {
        scheduleReactivate
        become(paused)
      }
    case "wakeUp" => // already awake
  }

  def paused: Actor.Receive = {
    case "doWork" => stash()
    case "wakeUp" => 
      unstashAll()
      become(running)
  }

  def scheduleReactivate: Unit = {
    system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(duration, self, "wakeUp")
  }

  def doWork(): Boolean = {
    // doing some work, then:
    calculateCondition
  }
}
```

Note: I have not tested this code! Should give you some ideas to work with, though.

Comment: the question is how an actor can sleep and wake up **itself**? there is no need in "case "wakeUp" => // already awake"

Comment: If you have a look at the code I gave, you will see that it changes its behaviour (to the "paused" behaviour - this is the safer way to cause an Actor to act "asleep"), and schedules a message to wake itself up later. Don't mix Thread sleeping with actors, and remember that actor =/= thread - if the actor doesn't receive any messages, it won't be tying up any threads.

Comment: in my example doWork() returns Unit.

Comment: Sure, but that is a minor implementation detail - just move the `scheduleReactivate` and `become(paused)` calls into `doWork()` if you want, or move the call to `calculateCondition` out - whatever makes the most sense for how `doWork` and `calculateCondition` function.